# Magento 2.4 | Cron job getting missed multiple times

Tags: cron, magento2.4

Please review the attached screenshot.

After upgrading Magento with latest version, we are facing this issue with cron. Cron getting missed multiple times. We have follow the below steps but still same result.

- Updated the cron timing.
- Disabled third party extension crons.
- Disabled the third party extensions as well.
- Updated server memory limit.

Please let us if any one has faced same issue before.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Have you check the log?

Comment: Yes, Not error log found. In cron.log, system.log and exception.log, not specific error found.